# SQLite on Android with FT3 - unable to delete specific row from search table

Tags: android, sqlite, full-text-search

In my Android app I've created a virtual table using FT3 for searching. The table creates, populates fine (using data from other tables) and the search works fine. I can also remove all the rows from the virtual table (using 'DELETE FROM '+ SEARCH_TABLE), however I seem unable to delete a specific row from the search table.

The virtual table structure is as follows:

```
public void createSearchTable(SQLiteDatabase db){
        String sql = "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE "+SEARCH_TABLE+" USING FTS3 (" +
                SEARCH_C_ACTID + " text, "+
                SEARCH_C_TEXT + " text, " +
                SEARCH_C_COURSETITLE + " text, " +
                SEARCH_C_SECTIONTITLE + " text, " +
                SEARCH_C_ACTIVITYTITLE + " text " +
            ")";
        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

Note I've tried creating the SEARCH_C_ACTID as both text and int - but with no resulting difference.

However when I try any of the following, nothing happens in the search table (I get no errors, and shows that no rows were affected by the delete query):

```
String s = SEARCH_C_ACTID + "=?";
String[] args = new String[] { String.valueOf(activityDbId) };
int result = db.delete(SEARCH_TABLE, s, args);
Log.d(TAG,"delete query result: " + result);
```

and:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM "+ SEARCH_TABLE + " WHERE "+ SEARCH_C_ACTID + "=" + activityDbId ;
Log.d(TAG,sql);
db.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

and:

```
String sql = "DELETE FROM "+ SEARCH_TABLE + " WHERE "+ SEARCH_C_ACTID + "='" + activityDbId +"'";
Log.d(TAG,sql);
db.rawQuery(sql,null);
```

For info, I have checked that the activityDbId value does actually exist as a row entry for the SEARCH_C_ACTID column in the search table.

Any help or assistance is very much appreciated.

Comment: The queries that search for a string should work (if inefficiently). Why are you not using the `docid`, or `MATCH`?

Comment: Thanks @CL - the reason for not using Match or docid is that this activityId is a reference to data in the original (non FT3) table, so I do want an exact match on the whole table cell, rather than just part of the string. Possibly a better approach would be for me to enter the activityid in the docid column since they should be unique ids.

Comment: Just updated now to put the activityId in the docid column and appears to be working well now